# Android Studio does not debug some classes

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

Android Studio does not debug some classes.

I'm working on a project with multiple layers and for some reason my android studio doesn't show the class debugs after the viewmodel, is there any configuration that could be missing?
Thank you very much in advance.

I made the recommended settings, I even changed machines and even then, it doesn't debug.

Comment: What do you mean with "after the viewmodel"? Could you include some code including the log statements that should be printed?
Also make sure in the Logcat window in Android Studio that you don't have any text filter applied by accident.

Comment: Are you referring to the debugger, or logging?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try to explore this page in android studio settings.
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping

Play with the settings and see if it fits you need